# How do I specify the URL to a WebSocketServlet in Jetty?

Tags: servlets, annotations, jetty, websocket

I have read [Creating a WebSocket-Chat-Application with Jetty](http://java.dzone.com/articles/creating-websocket-chat) and I would like to create a simple echo websocket using a `WebSocketServlet` on Jetty.

I have created my `WebSocketServlet` like this:

```
public class ChatSocketServlet extends WebSocketServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><h1>Chat</h1></body></html>");
    }

    @Override
    public WebSocket doWebSocketConnect(HttpServletRequest request, String protocol) {
        return new ChatWebSocket();
    }

    class ChatWebSocket implements OnTextMessage {

        private Connection connection;

        @Override
        public void onClose(int closeCode, String message) {
            System.out.println("onClose");
        }

        @Override
        public void onOpen(Connection connection) {
            this.connection = connection;
        }

        @Override
        public void onMessage(String data) {
            try {
                connection.sendMessage(data);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

But what URL should I use to connect to this websocket? It seems that I can't use the  `@WebServlet` (e.g. `@WebServlet("/HelloServlet")`) as I can with `HttpServlet`. I have tried to connect to:

```
ws://localhost:8080/MyJavaWeb/ChatWebSocket
```

but it returns `Not Found`. Is there any other annotation to specify the URLs for `WebSocketServlet`? And I don't know the URL for getting the output from `doGet` on this servlet either.

Comment: What's your URL mapping in your web.xml file ?

Comment: @nico_ekito: I don't have a `web.xml` I only use the annotation `@WebServlet("/HelloServlet")` instead, but it doesn't seem to work for this.

Comment: Since the Websocket are not a part of the JEE specs, I'll try with a web.xml file :)

Comment: @Jonas did you manage to get it working? I'm having the same issue. even if I can get http 200 from my websocket client, but it still forcing to close the connection.